# Center and stretch images vertically, center horizontally

Tags: html, css, image-scaling

I want to scale images so that they are centered horizontally and vertically, and they are stretched vertically until they fill the whole screen vertically. There might be white borders.

Images should maintain their aspect ratio. I added a picture of what I wanted to do. Images should adjust to the resolution of the screen.

From top to bottom, there should be always an image. If you resize the screen the images should adjust and get smaller so the screen is still filled vertically with 3 images from top to bottom.

I don't know how to explain it more clear...

[image]

This is what i got:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body html{
        text-align:center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    #grid {
      height: 100%;
      position:absolute;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .grid-element {
      width: auto;
      height: 33%;
      float: left;
    }

    .stretch {height:100%; width: auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid">
    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/bscasino.jpg" class="stretch" />
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/frankpollet13.jpg" class="stretch"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/groep.jpg" class="stretch"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/groepbscasino.jpg"  class="stretch"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/kleurpotloden.jpg" class="stretch" />
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/paulverrept.jpg" class="stretch" />  
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/penselen.jpg" class="stretch" />  
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/groep.jpg" class="stretch" />  
    </div>

    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="fotos/groep.jpg" class="stretch" />  
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

URL:
http://www.voorleestoer.be/test/

Comment: It's not clear what your question is—or what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added an image with the design I'd like to make.

Comment: @Fl1p - you are actually saying the "design" image means anything to others? all I see is a bunch of rectangles. Please try harder to explain yourself...

Comment: Ok, I understand what you want, it's very easy to make. give me a minute

Comment: My English is not that good... I only speak code. And still... :)

Comment: When an image becomes wider than a 3:rd of the browser view port, should it be cropped? .. Do you need to support older browsers?

Comment: Good question... Yes, it may be cropped, preferably the same from each side of the image.
It would be nice if I could support the latest versions of IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start how to have a 3x3 grid cover the height. The width is set to 90% but you can set it how ever you wish, using min/max-width also limit it for bigger/smaller screens.

This will give you an even sized square of images and smaller ones will scale up to fit height and bigger scale down and all of them crops equally on each side.

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-row {
  height: 33%;
}

.grid-element {
  width: 30%;
  height: 94%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img1, .img4, .img7 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150x50);
}

.img2, .img5, .img8 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x200);
}

.img3, .img6, .img9 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/550x350);
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">

      <div class="grid-row">

        <div class="grid-element img1">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-element img2">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-element img3">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="grid-row">

        <div class="grid-element img4">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-element img5">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-element img6">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="grid-row">

        <div class="grid-element img7">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-element img8">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-element img9">
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your answer later today!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I need! I changed the border and margins, and now it's perfect for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the demo:

**https://jsbin.com/rafute/edit?css,output**

### CSS:

```
html, body{
  text-align : center;
  margin     : 0 auto;
  height     : 100%;
}

#grid {
  position  : absolute;
  top       : 0;
  bottom    : 0;
  left      : 0;
  right     : 0;
  margin    : 0 auto;
  font-size : 0; 
}

.grid-element {
  width    : 33.333%;
  height   : 33.333%;
  float    : left;
  position : relative;
  overflow : hidden;
}

.grid-element img{ 
  position  : absolute;
  top       : 50%;
  left      : 50%;
  width     : 150%;
  transform : translate(-50%,-50%);
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #grid .grid-element img{ height:100.5%; width:auto; }
}
```

This will effectively render a `3x3` grid of images which will **always** fit in the browser window, and the images will fill the grid as perfectly as they can, with some cropping of-course, because the images have their own *aspect-ratio* and the `3x3` grid has dynamic *aspect-ratio*.

Comment: Thanks, but what you made is a bit different. I find the height more important the the width. So the images should fit together from top to bottom, and no whitespaces are allowed between the images. Not on the side of each image, not down or above each image. Only right and left from the whole block. So they should stick together in a 3x3 formation side to side and bottom to top..

Comment: @Fl1p - it's unreasonable the window will be resized to half the width. and if so, you can add  mediaQuery [**like this**](https://output.jsbin.com/rafute). Also, the aspect-ratio of the photos is unkown, which makes it difficult to have a CSS-only perfect solution which is also responsive.

Comment: Allright. Too bad the images get cropped, but I'll be reasonable :p That's allready a better solution! Thanks for the great effort! I'll wait for a better answer, if it would be possible. If not, I'll mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: of course they get cropped, you they have their own aspect-ratio, which is a constant, and the aspect-ratio of the `grid-element` is dynamic because of browser resize. there is no better solution, unless you want to have the images stretched, but they will look distorted and pretty bad. this solution is the absolute best.